# Function fgetcsv won't parse file without blank line at end of file

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I'm working on a script to run through a CSV file (see [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612680/working-with-a-csv-with-odd-encapsulation-php)).

I ran into a weird thing, where if my actual CSV file itself has a blank line at the end of it, it will open and parse just fine, but if it doesn't, if the end of the file ends at the end of the last line, it just shows up blank.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's a file ending issue.  Check that your file has LF line endings, or check the parameters of `fgetcsv` to see if it supports Windows style file endings (if that is what your file is using).